# RabbitMQ C library how to do timed wait on amqp_simple_wait_frame?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, rabbitmq

I try to interrupt thread with RabbitMQ listner. Yet thread currently stays `amqp_simple_wait_frame` function. And it waits forewer. I wonder how to make `amqp_simple_wait_frame` be as thay say timed (so I could look if I shall terminate that thread or continue waiting)?

Answer (score 1):

The `amqp_simple_wait_frame_noblock` could be used which has timeout value as parameter. If timeout is NULL then func behaves as `amqp_simple_wait_frame` else waits to read frame till timeout is reached.